# is it possible to send the entire list of objects in a submit form with spring mvc?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to modify and send a list of objects using spring MVC.

I want , when I will click in the button that triggers the form submit, in the controller, capture all the list with the objects.

Unfortunately.. I have no idea how to do this.

So far I got this:

```
<@form:form modelAttribute="MyObject" method="post" action"somewhere">
    <@display:table list=myList id="myObject">
        <@display.column title="Name">
            ${myObject.name}
        </@display>  
        <@display.column title="value">
            HERE I SHOULD MODIFY EVERY OBJECT WITH AN INPUT, NOT SURE IF THIS WOULD WORK
            <form:input path=${myObject.value} id="value" />
        </@display>  
    </@display>
</@form:form>
```

And at my controller so far I have this:

```
@RequestMapping (value="myurl" method = Request.POST)
public void myMethod(@ModelAttribute Object myObjects){
    So here Id like to get the entire list of objects, but myObjects is null.
}
```

Any idea how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: You can set the parameter of myMethod to `Model model` and just do `model.addAttribute('myList', list);`  That should pass the list to your view.  From there it is up to you

Comment: then, should I create the method GET for this?

Comment: No, it should be ok.  It is just a dependency injection.  It should work with Post or any other method.  It just passes a view object up to the view.  You have to then loop through the list and present your data as you want.

Comment: so, I change it for @ModelAttribute Model model ?

Comment: Only if you have instantiated or defined the instantiation methods.  Otherwise you can just leave off the @ModelAttribute

Comment: What are the object types you are trying to submit?  Could you show them?

Comment: its a list of a custom object, the custom object has an ID and a list of longs inside, but its a custom type

Comment: Probably the best way to go would be to implement a custom `HandlerMethodArgumentResolver` that converts your form input to a `List<MyObject>` as a controller argument.

Comment: any idea how to do that?